# Code keeps going in an infinite loop. there is also an error at the end on the last line. Not sure why. I am new to coding

Tags: python

```
#import random library 
import random

#colors list array
colors = ["Red", "Blue", "Green", "Brown","Pink", "White", "Black", "Silver"]

#Print Welcome Message 
def welcome_msg():
    print("Wlecome to the guessing game! ")
    
#Generate the random index for the colors array list and return the index
def get_random_color_index():
    random_color = random.choice(colors)
    return random_color
    
#Get user guess input and return user input
def get_user_guess():
    userGuess = input("Pick a color of you choice: ").replace(" ", "").capitalize()
    while(True):
        if userGuess in colors:
            return userGuess
        else:
            print("Try picking a different color! ")


#check if user input and random index color matches
def check_guess_color_match(index, user_guess_color):
    return index == user_guess_color
    
##############Guess Game program#####################
#print welcome massage first
welcome_msg()

#Ask user to enter their guessed colors
get_user_guess()

#Get the random guess color based on the random index generator.
get_random_color_index()

#check if the user guess color matches the computer random color 
#based on the random index 
color_match = check_guess_color_match(get_random_color_index, get_user_guess)

#print if user guess correct or fail

if color_match:
    print("Congrats, you guessed the right color!! ")
else:
    print("You gussed wrong!, Try again ")


print("Computer picked" + " "+ get_random_color_index)
```

please don't change the functions and user input must accept all case options including space. for example, user can enter "Red", "red", or "RED" and extra space if entered by mistake( "  Red" , "Red   " , and "  red    ") and user input of color must be from list. if not then ask the user to re-enter.

Comment: clearly `user_guess` is not in `colors` ...

Comment: If "userGuess in colors" is false once, it is always false because the variables don't change in the loop.

Comment: "please dont change the functions" ... but your function is wrong ...

Comment: Your `get_user_guess` function doesn't actually let the user make another guess if their first one is wrong, because your `input()` call is outside the loop.

Answer (score 2):

There are two main problems: one is that when the user enters an invalid color, they don't get a chance to re-enter it, so the `while True` loop just forever prints the error message, since the `userGuess` variable never changes. You can rewrite that part like this to fix that issue:

```py
def get_user_guess():
    userGuess = input("Pick a color of you choice: ").replace(" ", "").capitalize()
    if userGuess in colors:
        return userGuess
    else:
        while userGuess not in colors:
            print("Try picking a different color! ")
            userGuess = input("Pick a color of you choice: ").replace(" ", "").capitalize()
```

The other problem is that you are passing functions, not function calls, to `color_match()` (and also not storing the result of the first call of `get_user_guess()`. You want to do this:

```py
color_match = check_guess_color_match(get_random_color_index(), get_user_guess())
```

instead of this (which is wrong):

```py
color_match = check_guess_color_match(get_random_color_index, get_user_guess)
```

(notice the parentheses)

or, as another user has mentioned, store the result of the first call of `get_user_guess()` and pass that to `color_match()`

Answer (score 1):

Please see a working version below

```py
# import random library
import random

# colors list array
colors = ["Red", "Blue", "Green", "Brown", "Pink", "White", "Black", "Silver"]


# Print Welcome Message
def welcome_msg():
    print("Welcome to the guessing game! ")


# Returns random color
def get_random_color():
    random_color = random.choice(colors)
    return random_color


# Get user guess input and return user input
def get_user_guess():
    userGuess = input("Pick a color of you choice: ")
    
    while True:
        if userGuess.replace(" ", "").capitalize() in colors:
            return userGuess
        
        else:
            print("Try picking a different color! ")


# check if user input and random index color matches
def check_guess_color_match(index, user_guess_color):
    return index == user_guess_color

##############Guess Game program#####################
# print welcome massage first
welcome_msg()

# Ask user to enter their guessed colors
get_user_guess()

# Get the random guess color based on the random index generator.
rnd_color = get_random_color()

# check if the user guess color matches the computer random color
# based on the random index
color_match = check_guess_color_match(rnd_color, get_user_guess)

# print if user guess correct or fail

if color_match:
    print("Congrats, you guessed the right color!! ")

else:
    print("You guessed wrong!, Try again ")

print("Computer picked" + " " + rnd_color)
```

Comment: Your answer would be better if you explained what you changed and why.

Answer (score 1):

I tried running this I did not get an infinite loop but one error at the last line

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\defaults\Desktop\t.py", line 52, in <module>
    print("Computer picked" + " "+ get_random_color_index)
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "function") to str
```

fixed that by storing generated color at line 38 in a variable and printing it worked fine for me.

```
color = get_random_color_index()

#check if the user guess color matches the computer random color 
#based on the random index 
color_match = check_guess_color_match(get_random_color_index, get_user_guess)

#print if user guess correct or fail

if color_match:
    print("Congrats, you guessed the right color!! ")
else:
    print("You gussed wrong!, Try again ")


print("Computer picked" + " "+ color)
```

Output I got

```
PS D:\defaults\Desktop> python .\t.py
Wlecome to the guessing game!
Pick a color of you choice: red
You gussed wrong!, Try again
Computer picked Pink
```

plus in your method get_user_guess() you don't need a while loop but need recursion to what you are trying to do.
This updated code will help.

```
#Get user guess input and return user input
def get_user_guess():
    userGuess = input("Pick a color of you choice: ").replace(" ", "").capitalize()
    if userGuess in colors:
        return userGuess
    else:
        print("Try picking a different color! ")
        get_user_guess()
```

I have fixed some things also you are not storing anything but calling random methods again and again which is leading to behaving it unexpectedly.

The final code would look like this:

```
#import random library 
import random

#colors list array
colors = ["Red", "Blue", "Green", "Brown","Pink", "White", "Black", "Silver"]

#Print Welcome Message 
def welcome_msg():
    print("Wlecome to the guessing game! ")
    
#Generate the random index for the colors array list and return the index
def get_random_color_index():
    random_color = random.choice(colors)
    return random_color
    
#Get user guess input and return user input
def get_user_guess():
    userGuess = input("Pick a color of you choice: ").replace(" ", "").capitalize()
    print (userGuess)
    if userGuess in colors:
        return userGuess
    else:
        print("Try picking a different color! ")
        get_user_guess()


#check if user input and random index color matches
def check_guess_color_match(index, user_guess_color):
    return index == user_guess_color
    
##############Guess Game program#####################
#print welcome massage first
welcome_msg()

#Ask user to enter their guessed colors
user_color = get_user_guess()

#Get the random guess color based on the random index generator.
color = get_random_color_index()

#check if the user guess color matches the computer random color 
#based on the random index 
color_match = check_guess_color_match(color, user_color)

#print if user guess correct or fail

if color_match:
    print("Congrats, you guessed the right color!! ")
else:
    print("You gussed wrong!, Try again ")


print("Computer picked" + " "+ color)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: and I am not sure about your logic for the success case also I guessed the correct color but still, the output was not correct 

Wlecome to the guessing game!
Pick a color of you choice: t
Try picking a different color!
Pick a color of you choice: y
Try picking a different color!
Pick a color of you choice: Red
You gussed wrong!, Try again
Computer picked Red